# Coded UI don't recognize the object with same name recorded earlier

Tags: c#, wpf, coded-ui-tests

I am working on UI Automation of WPF application. I am using *Coded UI* for the same.I use coded ui test builder to record different object on screen, while i am recording for the fist time objects are recognised in given **hierarchy**(*for eg*)

Application -> **BarManagerGroup** -> UIItem

But when i close Visual studio and my application then again try to capture the same object the hirerchy of recognition changes(*for eg*)

Application -> **BarManagerGroup1** -> UIItem

Because of this It's unable to recognise the Object.
Please give me any solution To this problem so that **object recognition hierarchy remain same** and **objects are recognized properly every time** ???

Comment: TIP: If the user interface (UI) changes, re-record the test methods, or the assertion methods, or re-record the affected sections of an existing test method.

Comment: But every day/time when i re-launch my application, I cant re-record the affected section.

Comment: Did you create the WPF app or is that a separate team/person? Do you know if there are AutomationProperties.AutomationId being defined on all UI elements?